# TFS 2010 Microsoft.Office.Interop Reference Woes

Tags: visual-studio-2010, office-interop

I'm about to go crazy with this problem!

1. I created a new server on a virtual
   machine for TFS.
2. I have created a new Build
   Definition, that when a solution is
   checked in from my local machine TFS
   is to build my solution using the
   default build process template.
3. On the TFS machine and my local
   machine I have MS Office 2010 and
   .Net framework 4.0 Installed.
4. In my project I have a reference to
   Microsoft.Office.Interop, etc...
5. This all build fine on my local
   machine.

The problem occurs when the build definition is triggered. The build is run and does it's stuff for a  while until it gets to the Microsoft assembly references.

- The type or namespace name 'Office'
  does not exist in the namespace
  'Microsoft' (are you missing an
  assembly reference?)
- The type or    namespace name
  'Application' could    not be found
  (are you missing a using    directive
  or an assembly reference?)
- ETC

The references paths point to the GAC, in case that matters.

Help would be awesome, and you would therefore be awesome by extension.

Regards,
Byron Cobb.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Byron,

If you take the assemblies from the compiled version on your computer create a libs folder at your solution level, then add the dlls for

1. Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll
2. Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll
3. Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.dll
4. OFFICE.DLL

Into the libs folder, then remove the reference to your Office Interop and add references to the following assembies in you libs folder, should work a treat, we build without office on our build server.

Regards

Iain

Comment: Thanks Iain! I find that there are no powerpoint interop dlls created when I build my local version. Is the powerpoint assembly part of one of the other dlls?

Comment: I ended up going to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA and getting the dlls out of there

Comment: No worries, Office Interop has been the bane of my life

Comment: It's not that bad. But thanks for the detailed answer, seems like best practise for VSTO + TFS

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for Web Site projects that use these DLLs.  Copying them into the bin folder doesn't allow TFS to see that these DLLs exist.

Comment: Try setting the property on the reference to copy local to true. if that dost work add the error to a question

Comment: do you still need an installation of MSword / Excel runtime?

Comment: Yes you do! https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb398242(v=vs.100).aspx